# Jenkins schedule pdi spoon job failing due to database connection error

Tags: jenkins, pdi, spoon

I have a jenkin scheduled job that calls Spoon ETL . On some days the job fails due to database connection error with SQL server as well as postgresql . I have tried running it by clearing cache as well as deleting database cache file. The error message is,

> Error connecting to database: (using class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the driver is out of date. Found a solution here: https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-109113

In summary it says:

**CAUSE:**

Issue is with JDBC 3.0 driver for Microsoft SQL Server (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). The platform upgrade replaced the current driver with an older driver.

**SOLUTION:**

1- Download most recent driver from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/

2- Copy file to PATH\TO\data-integration\lib

3- Delete existing driver. 
Note* DO NOT JUST RENAME IT.  If you just rename it, it will work in Spoon but not when you launch the job in AI.